# JQL: Show all sub-tasks of stories in current sprint

Tags: jira, confluence, jql

###Background###
I'm using Atlassian's Confluence to make a page where to display our teams subtasks. Subtasks that do not have the status *Done* will prevent the Sprint from being closed by the Scrummaster.

In our case, users do not assign values (like sprintvalue, assignee or status) with the same care as they do for stories and epics.
###Goal###
To make sure I have a list of all the subtask that would prevent a sprint from closing, I'd like to generate a list in confluence

```
All incomplete Sub-tasks -> that are part of a userstory -> which is the currently active sprint.
```

Currently, I have it set up like this:

```
type = sub-task AND status != Done AND parent =
```

The parent field only supports search by issue key or by issue ID, not by another query. This means that my original idea does not work:

```
type = sub-task AND status != Done AND parent = (type = story and sprint = "Sprint 1")
```

###Note###
I am in no position to use plugins.
Using Atlassian Cloud

###Answer###
As Kevin pointed out, and I already feared, this can only be done by using a plugin like scriptrunner. So far, the options seem:

1. Try and talk to admins, see if they can get clearance on a plugin.
2. Painstakingly input all the id's of the userstories in the JQL query.  This will take a few minutes to set-up every sprint, but it is as much work as clicking every story for sub-tasks.
3. Try to find a way to visualize this in Jira itself. Since everything is bolted shut for users, this might not be as straightforward as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will need a plugin to do that. I believe scriptrunner can do this, but there are surely others.

You might try an exotic workaround such as injecting data into your subtasks on transitions or other events of the parent issue. This way you can filter on the data in the subtask itself. However, I would not recommend this, as it can get very messy and it will be easy to get out of sync. Also, chances are large that you will also need a plugin for achieving that.

Another way of visualising this might be through a board in Jira. There you can visually see which subtasks are not done yet, and you might even play with quick filters, swimlanes or card colours to highlight some things.